# How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to set a maximum limit of rows in my MySQL table. Documentation tell us that one can use following SQL code to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_with_limit` 
   `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB MAX_ROWS=100000
```

But `MAX_ROWS` property is not a hard limit ("store not more then 100 000 rows and delete other") but a hint for database engine that this table will have AT LEAST 100 000 rows.

The only possible way I see to solve the problem is to use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger which will check the count of rows in table and delete the older rows. But I'm pretty sure that this is a huge overheat :/

Another solution is to clear the table with cron script every N minutes. This is a simplest way, but still it needs another system to watch for.

Anyone knows a better solution? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to make a restriction on adding a new record to a table. Raise an error when a new record is going to be added.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt >= 25 THEN
    CALL sth(); -- raise an error
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note, that COUNT operation may be slow on big InnoDb tables.

On MySQL 5.5 you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) // [RESIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html) statement to raise an error.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct as it is the most interesting one. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

- Create a table with 100,000 rows.
- Pre-fill one of the fields with a
  "time-stamp" in the past.
- Select oldest record, update "time-stamp"
  when "creating" (updating) record.
- Only use select and update - never use insert or delete.
- Reverse index on "time-stamp" field makes
  the select/update fast.

Comment: this seems like WAY more work than insert and truncate table when cap is reached.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to limit the maximum number of a table rows in MySQL, unless you write a Trigger to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making up an answer off the top of my head.  My assumption is that you want something like a 'bucket' where you put in records, and that you want to empty it before it hits a certain record number count.

After an insert statement, run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` which will get you the auto increment of a record id.  Yes you still have to run an extra query, but it will be low resource intensive.  Once you reach a certain count, **truncate the table** and **reset the auto increment id**.

Otherwise you can't have a 'capped' table in mysql, as you would have to have pre-defined actions like (do we not allowe the record, do we truncate the table? etc).

Comment: Truncate removes all rows in a table, not concatenate it to N rows :/

Comment: right... did I misunderstand? I thought you wanted to 'empty' the table when the limit was hit? No?

Comment: No, I need to remove obsolete (older) rows from table, not all of them :)