# Storing Only 10 rows in database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table)

How to store only 10rows in database if 11th added then the older one should be deleted.....

Brief Description :
Am creating a application pf password management, if user changes the password , the current password will be updated and the old password will be stored in other table with the timestamp of changed time....
and when he changes the password, it will check in the old password table list and if it exists it will give an message like u used this password earlier so give other name.....
Now what i want is only recent 10 passwords should be stored in passwordList table how to achive this.... 
THANKS IN ADVANCE...

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to store plain text passwords in database?