# Set the capacity in a mysql table so it can hold 150 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, capacity

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I want to set the capacity of a table so it can only store  150 rows. Is this possible? My table is InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using a trigger.

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table).

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt > 150 THEN
    CALL sth(); -- raise an error
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```