# Mysql registering with transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm looking for a solution for the following situation:

I have a tournaments table in mysql which has a maximum amount of sign ups.
When a sign up occurs it's inserting the row in the tournament_players table.

My main problem is I don't know how to avoid the case when two or more sign ups occur at the same time and they exceeds the maximum amount of sign ups.
I was researching about the transaction but I don't really understand how it works in practice. May I lock only the row or the whole table? AFAIK I know first needs InnoDB the second need MyIsam. Which is the best for my problem?

Comment: My question is just theoretically yet. I'm wondering about a solution now when I have a counter col on the tournaments table which I try to increment when a player sign up.

`UPDATE t SET count = count + 1 WHERE max > count AND id = tournament_id`

If I have an affected row I save the sign up otherwise don't.
What you think about it?

Comment: you should put the code of your comment back in the question (edit the question)

Comment: @akos, Have you bee able to test this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Possible solution: [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table)
2. Have a function that checks the amount of rows in a table, if it exceeds what you want, dont run query and run error code instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but you may misunderstood me. Setting maximum number of rows doesn't fit my needs. I need to check if a user can sign up to a tournament without exceeding the maximum amount of sign ups and I'm afraid of a situation when two syncron request for a sign up beat each others and exceeds it.