# create table column count row limit

Tags: java, mysql, database, limit, column-count

I am creating a Java program that is connected with a MySQL database. I want to create a table in MySQL that has a limitation for 10 inputs or for 10 insert to statement. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I've only tried the select from limit but it only shows the first 10 when I want it to insert up until 10 inputs only

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing this question: [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table)

You should create a stored procedure to control that limit!